# Combining a Cell Reference and Wildcard as Criterion in Google Sheets CountIf Formula

Tags: google-sheets, cell, wildcard, countif

I'm struggling with writing the proper syntax for this formula in Google Sheets. In one sheet called Game Log, in the H column I have data that can be a range of names (1 - 10 names per row). I'm trying to construct a COUNTIF statement that would search for the name in all the rows for that column. There can be several other names in the same column so I need to use the wildcard * to find any occurrence of the name in each row. So for example, the current code below would count all occurrence of Adam in the rows.

```
=COUNTIF('Game Log'!H3:H102, "*Adam*")
```

What I would like to do is replace the hard codes "*Adam*" with a cell reference (in this case B2). Is it possible to combine that cell reference with the wild card? The know the code below doesn't work (as it would return text counting occurrences of B2), but is something like this possible?

```
=COUNTIF('Game Log'!H3:H102, "*B2*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
=COUNTIF('Game Log'!H3:H102, "*" & B2 & "*")
```

That ought to look for any string value, followed by the cell value, followed again by any string value. It's essentially just performing separate checks, in sequence, which allows you to search for different value types (in this case string wildcard + cell value + string wildcard).